# Can the universe's topology change during its evolution?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, topology, time-evolution

Jean-Pierre Luminet's talk from 2007 titled "Geometry and Topology in Relativistic Cosmology" (https://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3374) has the following statement about the time independence of the topology of the universe:

> [...] classical general relativity does not allow for topological
> changes during the course of cosmic evolution.

I am guessing this is a trivial statement perhaps involving the invariance of the topology of the solutions of a PDE, but there are no references about this in the talk. I am looking for a reference showing this result and perhaps going into more details of the underlying assumptions and how it would be different if quantum effects are included. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Just a comment to say that even if "topological change" means a change in topology, a change in topology doesn't necessarily mean "topological change" (because the last is referring to a change in homotopy or in simplicial homology for example). So what are you referring to when you say "topology change during evolution"? Is it a change in the set of local neighborhoods of points, or a change of the homotopy/homology groups of hypersurfaces (which is global)?

Comment: I mean the change in the global properties and I believe that's what Luminet meant as well. For example can the universe's topology evolve from being a simply connected topology to a multi-connected topology after the Big Bang?

Comment: I don't think so because diffeomorphisms are special cases of homeomorphisms, but this involves just my intuition. Moreover, general relativity is a theory of space-time, not space in time, so in this theory, the universe is to be thought of as a 4-dimensional object as a whole.

Comment: The problem with allowing the (spatial) topology to change is that it breaches the global hyperbolicity causal condition. If you drop this condition the topology can always change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some classic results showing, on Lorentzian spacetime, topology changes violate causality (Geroch proved this in the '60s) or cannot satisfy the Einstein equations with non-negative energy density (Tippler proved this in the '70s).

A decent review paper on topology change in classical Lorentzian GR:

- Arvind Borde, "Topology Change in Classical General Relativity", [arXiv:gr-qc/9406053](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9406053)